# where can i get the Microsoft-managed keys?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

Hi everyone im trying to receive my blob storage data via my spring boot client application. I can retrieve the data however it is encrypted.

In my Storage Account settings the encryption type is "Microsoft-managed keys". Now, where do find the key i need for decrypting my data? I am kinda confused i'm just not able to find the key.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The Microsoft managed keys used for encryption are not available to us and the decryption is taken care of transparently when you download the data using the SDKs or APIs. Are you sure that the data has not been encrypted before loading into the storage account? In which case you need to source the decryption key from the application which loaded the data into the storage account.

Comment: Thanks alot, the problem was that the picture got encrypted by uploading it via the graphical console. When uploaded via my application it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure Storage encrypts all data in a storage account at rest. By
> default, data is encrypted with Microsoft-managed keys

All data that is written into Azure storage will be automatically encrypted by Storage service prior to persisting, and decrypted prior to retrieval. Encryption and decryption are completely transparent to the user. All data is encrypted using 256-bit AES encryption, also known as AES-256—one of the strongest block ciphers available. With encryption enabled by default.

Reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/announcing-default-encryption-for-azure-blobs-files-table-and-queue-storage/

**And The Microsoft managed keys used for encryption are not available**

In Your scenario check the encryption type at the **client side Data that is already encrypted when it is received by Azure. With client-side encryption, cloud service providers don’t have access to the encryption keys and cannot decrypt this data. You maintain complete control of the keys.**

For more details refer this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/encryption-atrest